# I'm having trouble trying to centre a div wrapper within a row

Tags: html, css, image, centering

I have tried lots of things including some examples from here but I'm clearly not coding it right and I've spent too much time on it already, so I'm asking for help.

I have an image sprite that is contained inside a wrapper div. All I want to do is centre the wrapper inside a row. Sounds easy I know, but I've tried and the only way I can do it is to set a width on the wrapper but I don't want that as it needs to be responsive as smaller screen widths.

The html for the content is

```
<div class="row row-centered">
<div class="industry_logos col-centered col-max">
    <dl class="logo_links clearfix">
        <div class="logos-wrapper col-centered">
                <dt>Chas</dt>
                <dd><a href="#" rel="external" class="chas" title="Chas Accreditation">Chas</a></dd>

                <dt>Construction Skills</dt>
                <dd><a href="#" rel="external" class="const-skills" title="Construction Skills">Construction Skills</a></dd>

                <dt>Construction Line</dt>
                <dd><a href="#" rel="external" class="const-line" title="Construction Line">Construction Line</a></dd>

                <dt>European Builders Confederation</dt>
                <dd><a href="#" rel="external" class="ebc" title="European Builders Confederation">EBC</a></dd>

                <dt>Federation of Master Builders</dt>
                <dd><a href="#" rel="external" class="fmb" title="Federation of Master Builders">FMB</a></dd>

                <dt>SMAS</dt>
                <dd><a href="#" rel="external" class="smas" title="SmartSafe">SMAS</a></dd>

            <div class="clearfloat"></div>  
        </div>      
    </dl>
    <div class="clearfloat"></div>
</div>
</div>
```

The CSS I am using is as follows.

```
    .industry_logos{margin:0 auto;}
.logos-wrapper{ margin:0 auto;}
.industry_logos dl.logo_links dt {
    display:none;
}

.industry_logos dl.logo_links a {
    display:block;
    float:left;
    text-indent:-9000px;
    overflow:hidden;
    background:url(../img/logos/logo_sprites_med.png) no-repeat;
    margin-right:10px;
}

.industry_logos dl.logo_links a.chas {
    background-position: 0px -63px;
    width:72px;
    height:56px;
}

.industry_logos dl.logo_links a.chas:hover {
    background-position: 0px -1px;
    width:72px;
    height:56px;
}

.industry_logos dl.logo_links a.const-skills {
    background-position: -72px -65px;
    width:113px;
    height:56px;
}

.industry_logos dl.logo_links a.const-skills:hover {
    background-position: -72px -3px;
    width:113px;
    height:56px;
}

.industry_logos dl.logo_links a.const-line {
    background-position: -185px -62px;
    width:100px;
    height:56px;
}

.industry_logos dl.logo_links a.const-line:hover {
    background-position: -185px 0px;
    width:100px;
    height:56px;
}

.industry_logos dl.logo_links a.ebc {
    background-position: -285px -62px;
    width:58px;
    height:56px;
}

.industry_logos dl.logo_links a.ebc:hover {
    background-position: -285px 0px;
    width:58px;
    height:56px;
}

.industry_logos dl.logo_links a.fmb {
    background-position: -344px -62px;
    width:47px;
    height:56px;
}

.industry_logos dl.logo_links a.fmb:hover {
    background-position: -344px 0px;
    width:47px;
    height:56px;
}

.industry_logos dl.logo_links a.smas {
    background-position: -394px -62px;
    width:110px;
    height:56px;
}

.industry_logos dl.logo_links a.smas:hover {
    background-position: -394px 0px;
    width:110px;
    height:56px;
}

.industry_logos.col-centered {
display: inline-block;
float: none;
text-align: left;
margin-right: -4px;
/* Contact Form */

table {
    width:100%;
    padding:5px;
}


/* Centred Row Styling */
.row-centered {
    text-align:center;
}
.col-centered {
    display:inline;
    float:none;
    /* reset the text-align */
    text-align:left;
    /* inline-block space fix */
    margin-right:-4px;
}
.col-fixed {
    /* custom width */
    width:320px;
}
.col-min {
    /* custom min width */
    min-width:320px;
}
.col-max {
    /* custom max width */
    max-width:320px;
}

/* visual styles */
body {
    padding-bottom:40px;
}
h1 {
    margin:40px 0px 20px 0px;
    color:#95c500;
    font-size:28px;
    line-height:34px;
    text-align:center;
}

[class*="col-"] {
    padding-top:10px;
    padding-bottom:15px;
    border:1px solid #80aa00;
    background:#d6ec94;
}
[class*="col-"]:before {
    display:block;position:relative;
    content:"COLUMN";
    margin-bottom:8px;
    font-family:sans-serif;
    font-size:10px;
    letter-spacing:1px;
    color:#658600;
    text-align:left;
}
```

I can't post the image due to low reputation. Solutions would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: A fiddle would be welcome

Comment: ok so I think it's sorted but not the perfect solution. I removed the "col-centered" class on the industry logos and logos-wrapper divs and the box jumped into the centre. It now adjusts as I reduce the browser window. Next step is to try and get each separate image to be centred as they wrap onto the second line. :)